# Searching for DATA (VBA+Web)

Tags: excel, web-scraping, vba

I'm trying to create a macro that fetch for specific DATA in URL from Excel sheet and when the DATA is found , it copy the values and past it into the Excel File andmove on to the next DATA

I'm a little bit new with SCRAPPING WEB via EXCEL VBA so Anyone can light me and helps me to carry on ?

- I made a lot of searches here in stack over flow but I didn't understand too much

I will explain below with Image what I want to Do and I will show My code which is nothing :(

First URL to use to access to `MP` :http://XXXX-XXXXX.eu.airbus.XXXX:XXXXX/XXXX/consultation/preSearchMP.do?clearBackList=true&CMH_NO_STORING_fromMenu=true

[image: Image One]

**then Take a value from EXCEL FILE and put it in that Path to make search and tape enter**
[image]

**The last Picture IT will loop for `MOD` and Copy Value and Paste it into Excel File**

[image]

Can Anyone guide me please with something

this is my first Code

```
Dim str As String: str = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1").Range("A1").Value    
Dim myURL as String
' The & symbol concatenates strings. The _ symbol is for line continuation.
 myURL = 
 "http://Confidential.eu.airbus.Confidential:Confidential/Confidential/" _
     & "consultation/preViewMP.do?" & str
```

Comment: To be able to help you go further with your script, you need to find the HTML elements that you want to interact with. These can be found if you press F12 in your browser. I know that Chrome and Edge will highlight the elements on the page, when you hover over them in the Developer Tool window (after pressing F12)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your URL then the next stage is to send it. To send it you need something to act as a connector, like Internet Explorer, or a background connector without the browser like XMLHttpServer objects - [THIS](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) is a good guide to hopefully get you started.

Comment: this Topic is good , I'm gonna carry on with coding until I get a problem to post it here

Comment: It's great, I ended up using it all the time at work, I've built a lot of handy tools that save people a lot of time automating annoying admin jobs they do through POST and GET requests. Just all background internet stuff, filling in forms etc.

Comment: Oh and yeah, if you get specific coding problems related to that then please post here!